# Cache when using pipieline from huggingface

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

When I load and run a pipeline in huggingface, something is cached and it changes the results in the pipeline.
I would like to free the cache completely. I already tried:
`gc.collect()` and `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`
but it still doesn't work.

This is my Code:

```py
tokenizer_1 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_1)
model_1 = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_1, device_map=device_1,torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

pipe= pipeline(
    "text-generation",    
    model=model_1,        
    tokenizer=tokenizer_1,   
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,  
    max_new_tokens=500,  
    min_new_tokens=-1, 
    do_sample=True,          
    top_k=50,      
    top_p=1, 
    repetition_penalty = 1.15, 
    temperature=0.01
)

 outcome= pipe(input)
```

After I just loaded the model I have 25441MiB on my GPU.

After I run it one or more times, it increases and stays at 26305MiB.

I want to get rid of the extra memory since it seems to affect the outcome of my pipe.

Comment: What is the value of `model_1`? Why do you think it affects the outcome of your pipe?

Comment: Its just llama-13b-chat from huggingface. When i run the model with the same input i get different results. That confuses me. And the increase in memory after i sucessfully ran the pipeline once also confuses me.